# Python How to Create a web app using Tweepy on WIndows

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, web-applications, tweepy

I have a simple python application which retrieves my tweets. I am using Tweepy API and the program is running fine when invoked using `python mytweets.py`

Code:

```
   import tweepy
   consumer_key = ''
   consumer_secret = ''
   access_token=''
   access_token_secret=''
   auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
   auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
   api = tweepy.API(auth)
   user = api.get_user('narendramodi')
   for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=user.screen_name).items(20): 
        print status.text.encode('utf-8')+'\n'`
```

Now, when I convert the same program to a web app by adding some extra codes, it throws an error stating `ImportError: No module named tweepy`

Code:

```
 import webapp2
 import tweepy

 class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
       def get(self):
           self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
           #same code


  app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)
```

What changes should i do to ensure the module tweepy is recognized?
I had installed tweepy using `python setup.py install`

I want to deploy this app to Google app engine.

Comment: install tweepy first using `pip install tweepy`

Comment: i did.
still I am getting the error